# Error trying to get the names of the tables in my Android SQLite Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

I am attempting to list all the tables I have in my database in a list view by creating a string array of the table names then passing them to a listView, I have a button which calls the activity which creates the listview. the activity calls getDbNames from my database class. I get this error in LogCat in eclipse:

Tag - CursorWindow
Text - Bad request for field slot 1,-1. numRows = 3, numColumns = 1

I'll include my whole database class to see if you  can help.

```
package the.paddox.pool;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class Database {

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "newplayersname";
public static final String KEY_PERCENTAGE = "percentage";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "paddoxa";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "players";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

public static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
                );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}

public Database(Context c){
    ourContext = c;
}

public Database open() throws SQLException{
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();
}

public long createEntry(String name) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}

public String[] getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_NAME};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result ="";
    String[] mString = {""};
    ArrayList<String> playersData = new ArrayList<String>();

    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        result = c.getString(iName);
        playersData.add(result);
    }
    mString = (String[]) playersData.toArray(new String[playersData.size()]);
    return mString;
}

public String[] getDBNames() {
    String[] result = null;
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    result = new String[c.getCount()];
    int i = 0;
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        result[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DATABASE_TABLE));
        i++;
    }
    return result;
}


}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think,you are getting this error because where you try to get `iName`,you haven't call `c.moveToFirst();` before that statement!

Instead you can use it like:

```
for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
    result = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME));
    playersData.add(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please check your Query

```
"SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'"
```

in **getDBNames()** as it list rows for column for `name`

your

```
c.getColumnIndex(DATABASE_TABLE) // DATABASE_TABLE = "players" in your code.
```

will actually not work and return as -1.

For details check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnIndex%28java.lang.String%29).

Hope this will help you to work further.